# Tsql KeyError Message with Python

Tags: python, string, pyodbc

The following Python code works fine:

```py
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r"SERVER=db.analytics.com;"
    r'DATABASE=Reporting;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password;'
)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
curs = cnxn.cursor()
```

But when I try this:

```py
abc="db.analytics.com"

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r"SERVER={};".format(abc),
    r'DATABASE=Reporting;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password;'
)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
curs = cnxn.cursor()
```

I get an error like the following:

> KeyError: 'SQL Server'

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).
So when you do this:

```py
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
r"SERVER={};".format(abc)
```

It's actually:

```py
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={};'.format(abc)
```

Thus, [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is trying to find and substitute keyword argument `SQL Server`.
That's why you are getting the error `KeyError: 'SQL Server'`.

To avoid this behaviour you can concatenate strings with `+` like this:

```py
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};' +
    r"SERVER={};".format(abc),
    r'DATABASE=Reporting;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password;'
)
```

Or even better, escape the braces by doubling:

```py
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};'
    r"SERVER={};".format(abc),
    r'DATABASE=Reporting;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password;'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to assign abc value using below code & it working properly.

```
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r"SERVER="+abc+";",
    r'DATABASE=Reporting;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password;'
)
```

I hope above solution will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah, it' s working but any solution with using .format()?